# New webserver: What all user accounts should I create and permissions to provide for

Tags: debian, permissions, security, users, webserver

This is a followup on my question [here](https://superuser.com/q/655123/151431).

I am setting up the first webserver and am fumbling with what user accounts to create and permissions to provide for better security. Below is what I have.

For 2 developers, I have 2 accounts (and they are added to the supplementary group `devs`) and only they are allowed to ssh to the server. For the web application (Django based), I have created 1 normal user, `app` (haven't configured it as `--system` user and belongs to group `app`) with shell access. The 2 developers, after ssh to the server, will su to `app` for any updates and starting/stopping the application. User `app` is not allowed to perform `su` (blocked by not adding to the group setting in `/etc/pam.d/su` using `pam_wheel.so`). I also have a 3rd account with no `su` capabilities for backup related tasks where a cron job will ssh and fetch log files, status, etc.

Let me know if security aspects need to be made better. (PS: I am a novice here)

Comment: Instead of the developers having to `su app` maybe you could use either file system ACLs to give appropriate default access rights to the user app. Or `chown` all appropriate files from the developers to app either in a cron job or on demand (monitoring the files with a FAM daemon).

Comment: @peterph Yes, doing `su app` will gradually turn out to be a pain in the process. But I guess I don't know how to do what you said. May be an example will help?

Comment: see @dannbysauer's answer - it's exactly what I have had in mind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su` requires sharing a password.  I prefer sudo.  So, developers would run either `sudo -u app command` to run `command` as `app`, or run `sudo -u app -i` to start an interactive shell as `app`.  Possibly `sudo -u app -i /bin/bash` if you've set `app`'s shell to something like /bin/false or /bin/true.

If they don't need a full shell as the app, but rather only need to restart the app, you can limit the commands they can run as app.  Use a default ACL on the directories they need to access which grants access to the devs and to the app so you don't have filesystem permission issues.  The principle of least privilege is what you need to follow, IMHO.  If they don't need to do it, don't give them access to do it.

Typically I prefer to use keys only for ssh.  If you can do that, disable passwords for the devs, and set the sudo rules to not require a password.  Then there's no passwords needed for anyone, and thus no password to disclose / lose / reset.

Reading assignment for this evening, because it's a bit much for this post: "how do filesystem ACLs work" and "how do I configure sudo".  Perhaps followed by managing ssh keys.

Comment: Well, I know sudoers.d/* format and sshd_config setup. Not conversant with fs ACLs. Are you harping on setfacl/getfacl?

Comment: 'you can limit the commands they can run as app' -- yes, I am having small bash scripts that for eg control the app via supervisorctl and currently running only them from `app` user using sudo configuration and without password.

Comment: Yes, I have blocked password for 1 user of the dev group. But enabled password access for the other -- just in case if my work machine crashes or backups die. However, I am planning to setup fail2ban, so hoping password access for the single user shouldnot pose any threat. BTW, for both users, I have passphrase -- don't feel too comfortable without it.

Comment: '...and thus no password to disclose' Isn't in that case you need to share the priv keys?

Comment: Each user gets a unique private key, so they don't need to share.

Comment: And yes, setfacl. If you set a default ACL on directories, you can give any new files under there group write (or read, as appropriate) without depending on umask and sgid bits to allow collaboration. It makes long-term maintenance much easier, usually. In this case, set up a default with a user acl for the app and group acl for the dev group. Probably. Since they'll be able to do most stuff as themselves, the sudo rules can be simplified. And there's less reason for people to share credentials.

Comment: Here's a good starting point for ACLs: http://lithostech.com/2009/02/working-with-linux-filesystem-permissions-and-acl/

Comment: This is the ACL reference I typically share: http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/  It tells you all you probably ever wanted to know.